# Good book to help me relearn Algebra 1...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, self-learning

In 8th grade I took Algebra 1 and did not learn a thing.I am now in Cal AB and making B's.

I was hoping to reteach myself Algebra 1 this summer by watching [Khan Academy](http://www.khanacademy.org) and reading a book on Algebra 1. Any suggestions on what book that should be? Oh yeah, one last thing, I plan on becoming a theoretical physics major someday and understand all the math prior to Algebra 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a great book on High School Algebra which is specifically ment for self teaching:

Practical Algebra: A Self-Teaching Guide

I m not sure what level you are at, if you expand on that a little it will probably enable people to give you even better recommendations ! Check the book above online for content suitability.

Comment: Thank you ser that helps me a lot.