# Relearn mathematics

Tags: soft-question, big-list, self-learning, advice

I believe that this question is well known, but since I'm not a US resident and do wish to learn math according to the U.S. school syllabus I wish that somebody can help me.

At my first eight years at school, I was good at math. Suddenly, I was involved in car accident and couldn't attend school for a long time. I've missed a lot of subjects and couldn't complete it until the final exams.

I didn't fail at final math exams but the average grade I got can't satisfy me since I wish to be able to learn Computer Science at the university (I'm working today as a software programmer but I can't touch many subjects because of math knowledge limitations). I've registered to it (Hebrew University of Jerusalem) and accepted but at the start of the year I've realized that I don't understand the subjects so I've stopped my studies and wish to rebuild my mathematics knowledge before re enrolling.

Could somebody points me to a book/website/syllabus that's talks about mathematics from scratch (Algebra, Geometry, Trigonometry etc.)? I've learned at Israel, but I do wish to follow the standard U.S. high-school syllabus.

Thanks you very much!

Comment: I would also recommend proof strategy books, for example, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187340/expanding-problem-solving-skill/187500#187500

Comment: The textbooks at artofproblemsolving.com are more challenging but very good.

Comment: I would also recommend the book: What Is Mathematics? An Elementary Approach to Ideas and Methods, Richard Courant, Herbert Robbins, Ian Stewart (Editor)

Comment: I find it hard to believe the US STEM (Sci + Tech + Engr + Math) curriculum is anywhere near Israel's. Anyone have the PISA scores?

Comment: Thanks :). Actually they're not, Israel mathematics level, as long as I've heard, is very low. Because of that I wish to learn according to the U.S. syllabus. The university does not continues from the end of the Israeli math high school syllabus, they request from you to know a set of topics.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning mathematics as if an absolute beginner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/learning-mathematics-as-if-an-absolute-beginner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website I would suggest is Khan Academy: http://www.khanacademy.org/ Literally hundreds of videos on math from counting to differential equations and linear algebra.

If you want books (specifically, high school text books), I highly recommend the Saxon Math series.  I used these books from elementary math through precalculus (Saxon calls this Advanced Mathematics).  (FWIW, I'm now in Vector Calculus and loving it...)  Here's a link to the homeschool section--they will sell individual texts (rather than bulk orders) through this site: http://saxonhomeschool.hmhco.com/en/saxonhomeschool.htm

Khan Academy, though, is probably the best resource; plus, it's free! :)

Some helpful questions for syllabus information:

[In what order should the following areas of mathematics be learned?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21901/in-what-order-should-the-following-areas-of-mathematics-be-learned?rq=1)

[Good book to help me relearn Algebra 1...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103017/good-book-to-help-me-relearn-algebra-1?rq=1)

[Learning mathematics as if an absolute beginner?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22513/learning-mathematics-as-if-an-absolute-beginner?rq=1)

Comment: Another one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57472/study-order-for-high-school-math?rq=1

Comment: Hi! Thanks very much for your detailed answer and references :) it's really helpful to me.